# How to get all the xpath of the elements a Web Page using Robot Framework?

Tags: java, python, angularjs, xpath, robotframework

I'm using Robotframework to automate tests, it uses the Selenium2 Library and gives the opportunity to extend many libraries (Java, Python, AngularJS, etc.).

Here's my question.

Is there a way to get all the xpath of elements displayed on a page that match a certain criteria?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: May I suggest to rephrase your question to "Is there a way to get all the html elements displayed on a page, that match a certain xpath?". With the current wording it's quite ambiguous, and that's a reason for it to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the question the 2 ways I understand it - at least one should be the looked for ;)

Presuming the xpath is `//div` - e.g. "all `div` elements"

**1)** To count how many matching elements are there:

```
${count}=  Get Matching Xpath Count    //div    # note there's no xpath= prefix
```

As pointed out in the comments, the return value of `Get Matching Xpath Count` is of a String type, so if you want to use it for some numerical comparisons, you'd better cast it to int:

```
${count}=    Convert To Integer    ${count}
```

**2)** To get each element matching that xpath, and do something with it

```
${matched elements}=    Get Webelements     xpath=//div
:FOR  ${element}  IN  @{matched elements}
\   ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}      # will get the text of each matched node
\   Log  ${text}
```

Comment: Todor thanks a lot for the help!
Just one more thing, I get all the element texts now, I need to check if each of the texts exist in a file, I think another FOR loop should do the trick, but how is it done?
I have to check weather all the texts displayed on the webpage exist in the specific file or not.
Now I got the texts, and need to check if they exist in the file provided.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Load the file contents in a string; store all html text in a list. Loop over the list, run `Should Contain   ${file content}   ${a list member}` on each.

Comment: Just a quick note on `Get Matching Xpath Count` - it returns a **string** and *not* an **int**. If you need to do math with the count, you'll need to convert it first.

Comment: Good call @GregM, thanks for pointing it out (frankly - I didn't thought of it); I'll add it to the answer, not to bite someone.